# jquery mobile and phonegap back button on android

Tags: jquery, android, mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to create a mobile app on my android using jquery mobile's api. When I try to link something to another page, and I hit the android back button, another page shows up and its not the original page i was on.

```
<div data-role="page" id='home'>
<div data-role="content">
<a href='#next_page'>Next Page</a>
</div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id='next_page'>
<div data-role="content">
Content
</div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id='wrong_page'>
<div data-role="content">
Content
</div>
</div>
```

So if I'm at the home page, I click on the link "Next Page", I go to the next_page, but when I hit the back button on the android device, the wrong_page shows up. Any idea why this might happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a clue so far, I do see a typo: `<div data-role="page id='wrong_page'>` --> `<div data-role="page" id='wrong_page'>`

Comment: oh, it mustve just a typo, but theres no typo in my other code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a problem with the syntax of the HTML code. You can try:

1. auto generate the back button with jqm, see "Back" button links [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)
2. use the specific API to the [backbutton](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#backbutton) and hardcode the funct you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using different HTML files for pages, use data-rel="back" on the  tag instead of the "`#(tagID)`", this will take you to the previous page.

else if you are using DIV in same HTML file for paging. use ".hide" in your .js file to hide the div except which one you wanted to show, like this

```
$("#1stdiv").hide();
$("#2stdiv").hide();
$("#3stdiv").hide();
$("#4stdiv").show();
$("#5thdiv").hide();
```

to make that in backpage history, implement stack and pop the pages into the stack as soon as you entered in to the page then write *onclick* function on backbutton onclick which should shows top element in stack. 
like this

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 function onDeviceReady(){
     document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
 }
function onBackKeyDown(){
   //hide all div except the div which is in top of stack 
 }
```

But make sure are adding `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` or `<script src="phonegap.js"></script>` on HTML file when you are using in phonegap.